# as3 this.graphics calls do nothing

Tags: actionscript-3

class A:

```
[SWF(width='800',height='600',frameRate='24')]
public class A extends MovieClip {
   private var b:B;
   public function A(){
     super();
     b = new B();
     addChild(b);
     addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
   }
   private function update(e:Event):void {
     b.draw();
   }
}
```

class B:

```
public class B extends MovieClip {
    public function draw():void {
       //! following code works well if put in constructor, but not here
       this.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
       this.graphics.drawCircle(200,200,50);
    }
}
```

this.graphics calls do nothing in draw method, but work fine inside B`s constructor, what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the problem immediately. A couple of things to consider:

- Add a constructor to B that calls super()
- You are adding the event listener to A, so A must be on the stage before the ENTER_FRAME event will occur
- You probably want to first use graphics.clear(), and then end with graphics.endFill()

Comment: As Kai says, it seems that update() function is not triggered, so it is more than likely that A is not in the main display list. Add it to stage or inside something that is in stage. You may test it by putting a trace() inside the update().

Comment: a is on stage, B calls super, and any drawing code works inside update, but not inside draw called from update

Answer (score 0):

Weird that code works fine for me (Chrome on OSX).

The only way I can see it going wrong would be the Event Listener being called when b is null, so you could put a check there "if (b) b.draw();"

Or the movie is stopped (Like what happens in IE, where you need to click to enable the swf to run)